# How to achieve the below sequence?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, collections, sequence

How to achieve result sequence with the given 2 sequences ?

```scala
val seq1 = Seq("A","B","C")
val seq2 = Seq(1,2,3)

val Result = Seq("A1","A2","A3","B1", "B2", "B3", "C1", "C2", "C3")
```

Comment: How is this question related to apache-spark? Maybe you want to remove this tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [for comprehensions](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html) to find all combinations and concat the result into string:

```scala
val seq1 = Seq("A", "B", "C")
val seq2 = Seq(1, 2, 3)

val Result = for {
  s1 <- seq1
  s2 <- seq2
} yield s1 + s2
```